# Telnet into SMTP Port 25 gives Blank Screen

Tags: smtp, telnet

Just this morning the outgoing mail server stopped working.

When I telnet into 110 it connects to POP3 perfectly.

When I telnet into 25 it just goes to a blank screen with no error message.  Pressing any key terminates Telnet and returns to command prompt.

It seems that the Port is working.  The Server is also working since sending it from other location works fine.  Some how it is just the office that is affected, and only for Port 25.

Any idea what could be causing it?  The internet seems to work fine.  The Internet provider is not blocking port 25 - since it can reach port 25, just not successfully form a connection for some reason.

Comment: Could you name OS/Release you use? It should help to provide better fit tests and fixes.

Comment: Using telnet from windows is not a reliable way to test SMTP: Some "intelligent" switches will recognize the telnet protocol and not let it pass. Use netcat, or PuTTY in raw mode to test connectivity.